# Python sklearn OneHotEncoder: how to skip values that do not exist in the list

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn, one-hot-encoding

I would like to one-hot encode this list:

[0 0 1 1 1 2 2 2 4]

When I do, the one-hot encoder converts my 4 to a 3. That is, I get this:

```
(0, 0) 1.0
(1, 0) 1.0
(2, 0) 1.0
(3, 1) 1.0
(4, 1) 1.0
(5, 1) 1.0
(6, 2) 1.0
(7, 2) 1.0
(8, 2) 1.0
(9, 3) 1.0
```

I would like this (note the last row has changed):

```
(0, 0) 1.0
(1, 0) 1.0
(2, 0) 1.0
(3, 1) 1.0
(4, 1) 1.0
(5, 1) 1.0
(6, 2) 1.0
(7, 2) 1.0
(8, 2) 1.0
(9, 4) 1.0
```

Complete MWE:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
idvals = [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 4]
hot = OneHotEncoder()
h1 = hot.fit_transform(np.asarray(idvals).reshape(10, 1))
print(np.asarray(h1))
```

Working with Python 2.7.14 |Anaconda custom (64-bit)| (default, Dec  7 2017, 17:05:42)

How can I get the last row to be (9, 4) instead of (9, 3)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can generate the ndarray of interest comparing `vals` agains an arange up to the `max` value and use `broadcasting` to obtain a matrix from the result:

```
vals = np.asarray(idvals)
u = np.unique(vals)
vals_b = vals[:,None]
a = (np.arange(max(u)+1) == vals_b).view('i1')
```

---

```
print(a)

array([[1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 1]], dtype=int8)
```

If we build a sparse matrix from the array we indeed get as specified:

```
from scipy import sparse

print(sparse.csr_matrix(a))

(0, 0)  1
(1, 0)  1
(2, 0)  1
(3, 1)  1
(4, 1)  1
(5, 1)  1
(6, 2)  1
(7, 2)  1
(8, 2)  1
(9, 4)  1
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, but the reason I want to do this is because the value 3 can exist in a different list later on, which I will also want to one-hot encode, such that both encodings would have the same shape once converted to a numpy array. So both encodings should have shape (10, 5) when converted.

Comment: This does not seem like a right approach. If you're working with lists, I'd lookl into pandas and `get_dummies` @stats

Comment: Thanks @yatu, I looked at the page here: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.get_dummies.html and it seems to still only encode "what it sees", not "what it could see, which it could reasonably infer from present data".

Comment: Actually was doing something unnecessary, check now @StatsSorceress

Comment: Sorry, it still isn't working because I don't know what i1 is?

Comment: Well in your csr matrix all cells only contain ones @stats ?

Comment: It's now giving me something of shape (10, 11)

Comment: I fixed the shaping issue, but I still have a problem with not everything being encoded.

Comment: The value 4 needs to be encoded regardless of whether it appears.

Comment: My bad I was trying to get fancy elsewhere. Thank you again!